# Crear un .jar desde R

Tags: r, jar

Tengo código en R que deseo de exportar como .jar para que después se pueda llamar sin problema al .jar

¿Cómo podría exportar un .R como .jar?

Comment: Hola adamista, al menos que yo sepa no existe tal posibilidad, una consulta rápida en google no devuelve resultados satisfactorios. R es un lenguaje interpretado que requiere justamente su interprete propio que nada tiene que ver con Java.

Comment: Posiblemente busques esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840119/run-a-r-script-from-a-java-jar

Comment: @PeCaDe, ese enlace puede llegar a ser útil para el OP, el tema es que no está claro que significa "se pueda llamar sin problema al .jar", lo que ofrece el enlace es una forma de, si se quiere,  "empaquetar" un script de R e invocarlo desde el JAR, pero de cualquier forma seguimos necesitando el interprete R. Con lo cual el JAR no sería portable a equipos que no cuentan con R. Adamista, puedes agregar más detalle a tu requerimiento?

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. @PatricioMoracho me refiero a invocar un script R desde el .jar pasándole parámetros y teniendo que devolverlos a la llamada del .jar. La idea era portar dicho .jar a otros ordenadores que ya contaban con el intérprete R.